# How to use an accessor for imbricated data types?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js

I'm looking at information about [accessors](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#state-variable-accessors) in solidity/js for more complex data structures than just a public array/mapping.

How can i access the array in that code for:

```
struct AnotherStruct {....}
struct Example {
    uint example;
    uint[] exAmple;
    AnotherStruct[] strucs;
    mapping (uint  => AnotherStruct[]) structss;
  }
Example[] public examples;
```

From there i can do:

contractinstance.examples(index)  in JS

It returns an array of one element ( as the Struct) value : 'uint example'

How can i access the data in the struct from the examples public array?

- `uint[] exAmple;`
- `AnotherStruct[] strucs;`
- `mapping (uint  => AnotherStruct[]) structss;`

I was expecting an array with like this : [uint example;uint[] exAmple,AnotherStruct[] strucs,mapping (uint  => AnotherStruct[]) structss]

Where i could just have done array[3].iteration  or array[4][uint] etc. but that doesn't seem to work that way.

Can anyone help?